# crud admin generator not generating views for tables

Tags: php, generator

I am trying to use the CRUD-Admin-Generator (crud-admin-generator.com) and I'm following the installation instructions exactly, but at the point where I run

php console generate:admin

It will not generate the views for my database tables.
The command does not output any error and the database connection is OK. The website is generated successfully (actually it is working before the generate command).

Am I missing something to do which is not in the installation instruction or is a php requirement missing ?

here my commands I'm excuting:

1. git clone https://github.com/jonseg/crud-admin-generator.git admingenerator
2. cd admingenerator
3. curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
4. php composer.phar install
5. edit src/app.php and fill in db-data, leaving /resources as it is
6. create nginx virtualhost pointing root to admingenerator/web/
   -> admin website is working at this point correctly
7. php console generate:admin
   -> nothing happens, not even with -vvv (verbose) any output
   -> still no views for my tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tables must have a PRIMARY KEY, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE actor (
  actor_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  last_update TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (actor_id),
  KEY idx_actor_last_name (last_name)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

You must have in your tables something like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY  (id)
```